# Is the Rinkeby Test Network no longer supported by the Ethereum Protocol?

Tags: metamask, testnets, rinkeby

I'm attempting to create a Rinkeby test network account on metamask, firstly I've noticed it didn't appear on the networks drop-downmenu so create one manually and it indicated that it was created successfully. But when trying to enter the account I get this error below my screen :
"`Due to the protocol changes of Ethereum: Rinkeby, Ropsten and Kovan test network s may not work as reliably and will be deprecated soon"`

It's my first time using the tool as I'm following a tutorial online, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rinkeby and Ropsten testnets have been deprecated as of October 5th, 2022.

See: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059213492-ETH-on-Sepolia-and-Goerli-networks-testnets-

Comment: Oh thanks Yongjian I wasn't aware,  are the other testnet faucets as reliable,  i.e which of them would you recommend?

Comment: Goerli network is the one I recommend.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out. thanks again.